# Ways to publish new result for NP-complete problem

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

I am working on an NP-Hard problem. The state-of-the-art algorithm for my problem runs in O(3^n) time using dynamic programming approach. I changed the way the dynamic program works for my problem and it reduces the time complexity to O(n2^n). But, the main problem with my approach is the optimal result. More than 95% of the time my approach is giving the optimal output. Is there any way to publish my work by showing the results for the different data set. I am unable to prove the approximation ratio. Please give me any suggestion regarding this. Note: The Input size is 2^n

Comment: If it's a real-world problem with an empirical community interested in practical solutions, then there should be standard datasets to demonstrate the efficacy of your algorithm, which you should compare to other state-of-the-art ones, in terms of both quality and speed. If it's a theoretical problem, you'll have to obtain some sort of approximation guarantee, since unanalyzed heuristics are not too interesting theoretically.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you for advice. May I contact you through your personal email address. I  want to discuss few points.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot function as your mentor. I suggest contacting a local academic.